# Rustlings thread exercise, why do I NOT dereference Mutex(Struct)?

Tags: rust, dereference

I'm learning Rust and have no experience with threads. I'm going through the Rustlings course and I've solved the `threads1.rs` exercise, but I don't understand why my `Mutex` struct doesn't need to be dereferenced.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct JobStatus {
    jobs_completed: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let status = Arc::new(Mutex::new(JobStatus { jobs_completed: 0 }));
    let status_shared = Arc::clone(&status);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for _ in 0..10 {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(250));
            let mut status_shared = status_shared.lock().unwrap();
            status_shared.jobs_completed += 1;  // why not *status_shared?
        }
    });

    let mut jobs_completed: u32;
    loop {
        jobs_completed = status.lock().unwrap().jobs_completed;
        if jobs_completed < 10 {
            println!("waiting... ({} jobs done)", jobs_completed);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on [Chapter 16.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html) of The Book, I would have expected to need to assign to

```rust
*status_shared.jobs_completed
```

in order to *get* to the `jobs_completed` field, but that generates the error:

```
error[E0614]: type `u32` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |             *status_shared.jobs_completed += 1;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is the difference that the book gives a pointer to a simple type and the above code gives a reference to a struct?

Answer (score 7):

`status_shared` is of type `MutexGuard`. `MutexGuard` implements the [DerefMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-DerefMut) and [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-Deref) traits, with a deref target of `T` (the type which is stored inside the Mutex - `JobStatus` in your case.

When you use behind a `.` behind an object the rust compiler will automatically try to deref it into something where the requested operation can be performed. Therefore the explicit dereferencing is not necessary here. This behavior is described in the Rust book in the [Deref chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch15-02-deref.html)

Answer (score 3):

As @Matthias247 [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56625317/5397009), dereferencing is automatic when behind a `.`

Additionally, your attempt at explicit dereference fails because of operator precedence: `*status_shared.jobs_completed` is equivalent to `*(status_shared.jobs_completed)` so it attempts to dereference an `u32` and fails, but you want `(*status_shared).jobs_completed` in order to dereference the `Arc<JobStatus>`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#deref-behavior) automatically dereferences via the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait.

References:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#deref-behavior